# When writing a troubleshooting, should the "explanation part" that determines the cause start with "has" or "had"?

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

For example, there's an issue with the computer not powering on. In the "explanation" or "solving" section, should I write:

"The cable has been unplugged. Please plug it in."

OR

"The cable HAD been unplugged. Please plug it in."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one: "The cable has been unplugged." is correct.  Or for the scenario, perhaps "Please check that the cable has not been unplugged." is better.

You should use the present-perfect tense here:

> The present perfect tense says that an action was completed at a time before the present, and the results or consequences of the action are relevant now.

https://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/Past-Perfect-and-Present-Perfect-Tenses